# Carousel Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been staring at this same code for about 4 hours and have tried looking watching a few different tutorials. The problem is the slider loads, with spaces for 3 slides but it only displays the first slide.

All the images load fine(verified in browser) but the carousel wont change slides.

Please help, thank you!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<!--Familiar with CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
                    <div id="creativecommons" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#creativecommons" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li>
                            <li data-target="#creativecommons" data-slide-to="1" class> </li>
                            <li data-target="#creativecommons" data-slide-to="2" class> </li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="assets/images/slide1.jpg" alt="beach" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="assets/images/slide2.jpg" alt="beach" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="assets/images/slide3.jpg" alt="beach" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="irwtbawd/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few things wrong, in the top you have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">` delete that since that is supposed to be for CSS not JS files and you are already calling the bootstrap JS below. The other thing I see is that the boostrap.min.js is being called from a different root folder than the rest `irwtbawd/assets/` instead of like the other with just `assets/` could be an issue there with not linking to your assets correctly.

-- EDIT --

Also I just noticed you have wrong HTML tags in the second and third `<li>` items in the `carousel-indicators`

change:

`<li data-target="#creativecommons" data-slide-to="1" class> </li>
<li data-target="#creativecommons" data-slide-to="2" class> </li>`

to:

`<li data-target="#creativecommons" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
<li data-target="#creativecommons" data-slide-to="2"> </li>`

remove the word class.

Also here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cQJd5/1/) that I just threw together and you can test it out there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, removed the link stylesheet, and changed the directory path. Still nothing. Is there any other information I should provide that might make this easier?

Comment: Thanks Amir5000, I have an error that says my jquery script isnt loading properly. I double checked the link and it matches what google has, should i just download jquery and add it to the assets/js folder? Also thanks for creating that fiddle, I hvae to run now but I'll check it out later!

Comment: yeah I would do that. Its more reliable to have a backup in case the request fails.

Answer (score 0):

have You try to call it using javascript?:

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

Comment: I'm not using the command line for this project, I should have in retrospect. Is there a way I could test this not using the command line?

Comment: Also the carousel displays on the page, with the three <li> dots, but I cant move from the first loaded image.

Comment: Open you browser console and make sure that all your js and css is loading and not getting a 404.

Comment: What I imagine happening is you take samfch advice and try and call the plugin in your html file, open your browser console and it will error out saying that carousel cannot be found and you need to confirm your css and js is loading

Answer (score 0):

Just in case (for the uninitiated). There is no need for `Jquery`, just add this to the carousel's first div: `data-ride="carousel"`

```
div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000"  data-ride="carousel">
```